How do I upgrade a .NET Framework Visual Studio project to SDK style?
After using Microsoft Upgrade Assistant without changing my ASP.NET MVC project .NET Framework target (4.7.2), I get the following error. How can I get rid of it?

Error NETSDK1022  Duplicate 'Content' items were included. The .NET SDK
includes 'Content' items from your project directory by default. You
can either remove these items from your project file, or set the
'EnableDefaultContentItems' property to 'false' if you want to
explicitly include them in your project file. For more information,
see https://aka.ms/sdkimplicititems. The duplicate items were:
'Views\Web.config'; 'Web.config'; 'Web.Debug.config';
'Web.Release.config';...

Here is the initial portion of the resulting Visual Studio project. The problem is related to the OutputType field. None of the possible options allow me to debug or run the project as in non-SDK VStudio project file style:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
  <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
  <TypeScriptToolsVersion>4.3</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
  <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
  <EnableDefaultItems>false</EnableDefaultItems>
  <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
  <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
  <Optimize>false</Optimize>
  <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <Reference Include="System.Data.OracleClient" />
  <Reference Include="System.Net" />
  <Reference Include="System.Security" />
  <Reference Include="System.ServiceModel" />
  <Reference Include="System.ServiceProcess" />
  <Reference Include="System.Transactions" />
  <Reference Include="System.Configuration" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
<Compile Update="Models\ConnectionHistory.cs">
  <DependentUpon>devDeptModel.tt</DependentUpon>
</Compile>

...


The config files are impliciltly included by SDK style projects, but are also included in the project file, resulting in the error. As the message says: You can either remove these items from your project file, or set the 'EnableDefaultContentItems' property to 'false' if you want to explicitly include them in your project file - see this answer for details

I'm not using Net Core...

Sorry, I should have said "SDK style projects"

Ok, I'll test...

After removing *.config entries from the converted *.csproj file I get all the other errors like before: NETSDK1022 Duplicate 'Content' items were included. The .NET SDK includes 'Content' items from your project directory by default. You can either remove these items from your project file, or set the 'EnableDefaultContentItems' property to 'false' if you want to explicitly include them in your project file. For more information, see https://aka.ms/sdkimplicititems. The duplicate items were: 'Views\Account\AdminMenu.cshtml'; 'Views\Account\ChangePassword.cshtml'; ...

As in the answer linked above, by default the SDK will "Publish everything under wwwroot..."

To elaborate on @stuartd's comments: In a 'legacy' style project, files need to be explicitly included in the project. In an SDK style project, the SDK support includes all files in the project directory - essentially performing a **\*.*. The error and ways to resolve the error are documented in "NETSDK1022: Duplicate items were included".

So the first thing to try is? <PropertyGroup>   <EnableDefaultItems>false</EnableDefaultItems> </PropertyGroup>

Now the problem is <OutputType>Exe</OutputType> in the project file source. I've tested "WinExe", "Exe", "Library", etc. and none allow to run my project in the browser. Any idea?

Can you provide the .vcsproj file without personal privacy?

Here it is, see my edit.

The type is Library.
I found a sample sdk style project from GIthub:
https://github.com/xin9le/SdkStyle_AspNet/tree/main
To test the project,

I modifed the csproj file:

    false
    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)
    Library



and package version:
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" Version="5.2.9" />


In webconfig file

the .net framework version:
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" />
</system.web>

package version:
   <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.9.0" newVersion="5.2.9.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>

3.And modified the  Launchsetting.json file.
I copied it from asp.net core mvc template and select start IIS Express.
{
    "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
    "iisSettings": {
        "windowsAuthentication": false,
        "anonymousAuthentication": true,
        "iisExpress": {
            "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5522",
            "sslPort": 44344
        }
    },
    "profiles": {
        "http": {
            "commandName": "Project",
            "dotnetRunMessages": true,
            "launchBrowser": true,
            "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5019",
            "environmentVariables": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            }
        },
        "https": {
            "commandName": "Project",
            "dotnetRunMessages": true,
            "launchBrowser": true,
            "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7118;http://localhost:5019",
            "environmentVariables": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            }
        },
        "IIS Express": {
            "commandName": "IISExpress",
            "launchBrowser": true,
            "environmentVariables": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            }
        }
    }
}

